# Get progress of unzipping file in java

Tags: java, unzip, progress

So I'm making a downloader and unzipper for a game, but I am not able to get the progress of the unzipping. This is my unzip method:

```
static public void unzip(cachePart name) throws ZipException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Unzipping " + name.getFile());
        int BUFFER = 2048;
        long current = 0;
        File file = new File(name.getFilePath());

        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
        //String newPath = zipFile.substring(0, zipFile.length() - 4);

        int finalSize = zip.size();

        //new File(newPath).mkdir();
        Enumeration<?> zipFileEntries = zip.entries();

        // Process each entry
        while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements()) {

            // grab a zip file entry
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFileEntries.nextElement();
            current += entry.getCompressedSize();
            //long finalSize = entry.getSize();
            int percentage;
            String currentEntry = entry.getName();
            File destFile = new File(Data.SAVE_DIR, currentEntry);
            //destFile = new File(newPath, destFile.getName());
            File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();

            // create the parent directory structure if needed
            destinationParent.mkdirs();

            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(zip.getInputStream(entry));
                int currentByte;
                // establish buffer for writing file
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];

                // write the current file to disk
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);

                // read and write until last byte is encountered
                while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
                }
                percentage = (int) (current / finalSize * 100);
                System.out.println("finalSize " + finalSize);
                System.out.println("Current " + current);
                System.out.println("percentage " + percentage + "%");

                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }
        zip.close();
        System.out.println("Done unzipping " + name.getFile());
    }
```

So I tried to do some things, but I can't get the 2 different sizes I need.
Which I think are: The size of the uncompressed zip file and the size of the next file it's going to unzip.
I tried doing this with:

```
int finalSize = zip.size();
```

and

```
current += entry.getCompressedSize();
```

Comment: There is no accurate way of doing this without going through it twice. A compressed file is not even guaranteed to be smaller than original. Just come up with an infinite please wait.

Comment: Okay, so going through it twice isn't really an option and I should just present the players with a message: "Unzipping, please wait."?

Comment: Okay, that's a pity.

Comment: This is a case where gathering metrics is too expensive and not worth it. Unless your zip files are truly huge and then a 10 to 20 second extra wait does not really matter. You don't want user to think your program is hung. I just give a modal dialog saying please wait...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [Zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/).  It comes with a progress monitor and has worked well for me in the past.

Here is an example [from their forums](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/forum/index.php?topic=68.msg215#msg215) showing how to use it.  The example demonstrates zipping but the progress monitor works the same way for unzipping, as well.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.ZipParameters;
import net.lingala.zip4j.progress.ProgressMonitor;
import net.lingala.zip4j.util.Zip4jConstants;

/**
 * This example demonstrates ProgressMonitor usage. Progress Monitor
 * can be used to get the current progress information of the task
 * being performed by Zip4j.<br><br>
 * 
 * ProgressMonitor can be used to get information regarding any kind of task.
 * This example uses the adding files to Zip functionality. Information regarding
 * rest of the tasks is similar to this approach 
 */
public class ProgressInformation {

    public ProgressInformation() {

        try {
            // Initiate the ZipFile
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("c:\\ZipTest\\ProgressInformation.zip");

            // Set runInThread variable of ZipFile to true.
            // When this variable is set, Zip4j will run any task in a new thread
            // If this variable is not set, Zip4j will run all tasks in the current
            // thread. 
            zipFile.setRunInThread(true);

            // Initialize files to add
            ArrayList filesToAdd = new ArrayList();
            filesToAdd.add(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\sample.txt"));
            filesToAdd.add(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\myvideo.avi"));
            filesToAdd.add(new File("c:\\ZipTest\\mysong.mp3"));

            // Initialize Zip Parameters
            ZipParameters parameters = new ZipParameters();
            parameters.setCompressionMethod(Zip4jConstants.COMP_DEFLATE);
            parameters.setCompressionLevel(Zip4jConstants.DEFLATE_LEVEL_NORMAL); 

            // Add files to Zip
            zipFile.addFiles(filesToAdd, parameters);

            // Get progress monitor from ZipFile
            ProgressMonitor progressMonitor = zipFile.getProgressMonitor();

            // PLEASE NOTE: Below code does a lot of Sysout's.

            // ProgressMonitor has two states, READY and BUSY. READY indicates that
            // Zip4j can now accept any new tasks. BUSY indicates that Zip4j is
            // currently performing some task and cannot accept any new task at the moment
            // Any attempt to perform any other task will throw an Exception
            while (progressMonitor.getState() == ProgressMonitor.STATE_BUSY) {
                // ProgressMonitor has a lot of useful information like, the current
                // operation being performed by Zip4j, current file being processed,
                // percentage done, etc. Once an operation is completed, ProgressMonitor
                // also contains the result of the operation. If any exception is thrown
                // during an operation, this is also stored in this object and can be retrieved
                // as shown below

                // To get the percentage done
                System.out.println("Percent Done: " + progressMonitor.getPercentDone());

                // To get the current file being processed
                System.out.println("File: " + progressMonitor.getFileName());

                // To get current operation
                // Possible values are:
                // ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_NONE - no operation being performed
                // ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_ADD - files are being added to the zip file
                // ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_EXTRACT - files are being extracted from the zip file
                // ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_REMOVE - files are being removed from zip file
                // ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_CALC_CRC - CRC of the file is being calculated
                // ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_MERGE - Split zip files are being merged
                switch (progressMonitor.getCurrentOperation()) {
                case ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_NONE:
                    System.out.println("no operation being performed");
                    break;
                case ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_ADD:
                    System.out.println("Add operation");
                    break;
                case ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_EXTRACT:
                    System.out.println("Extract operation");
                    break;
                case ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_REMOVE:
                    System.out.println("Remove operation");
                    break;
                case ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_CALC_CRC:
                    System.out.println("Calcualting CRC");
                    break;
                case ProgressMonitor.OPERATION_MERGE:
                    System.out.println("Merge operation");
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("invalid operation");
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Once Zip4j is done with its task, it changes the ProgressMonitor
            // state from BUSY to READY, so the above loop breaks.
            // To get the result of the operation:
            // Possible values:
            // ProgressMonitor.RESULT_SUCCESS - Operation was successful
            // ProgressMonitor.RESULT_WORKING - Zip4j is still working and is not 
            //                                  yet done with the current operation
            // ProgressMonitor.RESULT_ERROR - An error occurred during processing
            System.out.println("Result: " + progressMonitor.getResult());

            if (progressMonitor.getResult() == ProgressMonitor.RESULT_ERROR) {
                // Any exception can be retrieved as below:
                if (progressMonitor.getException() != null) {
                    progressMonitor.getException().printStackTrace();
                } else {
                    System.err.println("An error occurred without any exception");
                }
            }

        } catch (ZipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ProgressInformation();
    }

}
```

Comment: I've never heard of this, I'll take a look at it, thank you for answering this old question!

Answer (score 1):

The correct example is:

```
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException;
import java.util.List;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.FileHeader;
import net.lingala.zip4j.progress.ProgressMonitor;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.unzip();
    }

    public static void unzip() {
        String source = "D:\\Downloads\\file.zip";
        String destination = "D:\\Downloads\\folder\\";

        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(source);
            ProgressMonitor progressMonitor = zipFile.getProgressMonitor();

            List fileHeaderList = zipFile.getFileHeaders();
            for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaderList.size(); i++) {
                FileHeader fileHeader = (FileHeader) fileHeaderList.get(i);

                System.out.println("Progress: " + (i + 1) + " / " + fileHeaderList.size());
                System.out.println("File: " + fileHeader.getFileName());

                zipFile.extractFile(fileHeader, destination);
            }
        } catch (ZipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```